# Convert iso8859-1 to utf8 in java

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

For an iso8859-1 encoded String s, what is the most elegant way to convert it to utf8?

```
String convertedString = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"); //is this correct, elegant etc?
```

NOTE I know that there are already questions similar to this one, but they ones I've found have ambiguous answers and do not show the whole conversion.

EDIT: more detalied description of my problem

```
//message is a String
//msg.setContent is this method http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29

msg.setContent(message, "text/plain"); 
msg.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");
```

When this is received in a mail client, the header says utf8 but the content (i.e. the message String) is actually iso8859-1 encoded, which leads to characters such as åäö being incorrectly rendered. What I'd like to know is how to make the contents utf8 encoded.

EDIT II: (answer) Turns out it was the MimeMessage.java class that set the encoding to iso8859-1 and instead of using MimeMessage.setContent there is another method MimeMessage.setText(String text, String charset); which allowed me to set encoding to utf8.

Comment: You don't convert a string; you simply choose the encoding when "serializing" it to bytes/"deserializing" it from bytes. Look [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html).

Comment: Apologies, but this just seems like semantics to me and I dont see how it answers my question. Also SO encourages pasting the whole answer and not just links to answers.

Comment: This is not semantics. A `String` has _no encoding_!

Comment: = only byte arrays have encodings?

Comment: Bytes produced from strings are the results of the encoding process; a `String` produced from bytes is the result of the decoding process. The link I posted explains all this (along with common misconceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't convert a string from one encoding to another. A `String` is a series of `char`s, and that's it. For what it's worth, it could be a series of carrier pigeons. Pigeons don't have an encoding. Neither do `char`s.

What you do is convert it to bytes when using a `Writer`. (or read from bytes when using a `Reader`). It is *at this point* that the encoding (a `Charset`) matters.

Comment: Cheers, this makes things clearer. If possible Id very much appreciate any feedback on the edited question.

Comment: Can you show the code you use for writing the mail body? My first guess would be that you don't specify an encoding when writing

Comment: Turns out it was the MimeMessage.java class that set the encoding to iso8859-1 and instead of using MimeMessage.setContent there is another method MimeMessage.setText(String text, String charset); which allowed me to set encoding to utf8. Cheers for your feedback though much appreciated and cleared things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. String is always in UTF-16. You can encode / decode only byte array.